# How to find the number of previous rows in which the range of values in two columns intersects with the range in the current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have I have data frame of rows with the values of open_time and close_time. I need to create column open_lvl_value where, for each row, will be shown sum of previous rows with intersected range of values. Probably I didn't explain it clear so I attached expectation and Gantt chart.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[40, 110],[50, 110],[70, 110],[90, 110],
        [100, 110],[40, 70],[50, 70],[50, 70],
        [60, 70],[60, 70],[100, 110],[130, 180],
        [150, 180],[150, 180]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['open_time','close_time'])
print(df)
```

```
    open_time  close_time
0          40         110
1          50         110
2          70         110
3          90         110
4         100         110
5          40          70
6          50          70
7          50          70
8          60          70
9          60          70
10        100         110
11        130         180
12        150         180
13        150         180
```

expected result:

```
    open_time  close_time  open_lvl_value
0          40         110               1
1          50         110               2
2          70         110               3
3          90         110               4
4         100         110               5
5          40          70               4
6          50          70               5
7          50          70               6
8          60          70               7
9          60          70               8
10        100         110               5
11        130         180               1
12        150         180               2
13        150         180               3
```

[Gantt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAivf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[40, 110],[50, 110],[70, 110],[90, 110],
        [100, 110],[40, 70],[50, 70],[50, 70],
        [60, 70],[60, 70],[100, 110],[130, 180],
        [150, 180],[150, 180]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['open_time','close_time'])


def foo(df):
    df['open_lvl_value'] = 0
    for row in df.itertuples():
        start = row.open_time
        end = row.close_time
        df_copy = df.loc[:row.Index]
        s1 = df_copy[(df_copy.close_time >= end) & (df_copy.open_time <= end)].shape[0]
        s2 = df_copy[(df_copy.open_time <= start) & df_copy.close_time >= start].shape[0]
        df.loc[row.Index, 'open_lvl_value'] += max(s1, s2)
    return df


print(foo(df))
```

```
Out:
    open_time  close_time  open_lvl_value
0          40         110               1
1          50         110               2
2          70         110               3
3          90         110               4
4         100         110               5
5          40          70               4
6          50          70               5
7          50          70               6
8          60          70               7
9          60          70               8
10        100         110               6
11        130         180               1
12        150         180               2
13        150         180               3
```